# Why can I not apply a different textColor to tabs?

Tags: android, tabs, styles

I've been making my own custom tabs and I want to change the textColor of the Tab based on whether or not it is selected.

I created my own style in "values", which is designed to only change the textColor:

```
<style name="TabTextStyle" parent="@android:attr/tabWidgetStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/tab_text_color</item>
</style>
```

... based on a drawable that considers "state_selected":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:state_selected="true"/> 
    <item        
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</selector>
```

Then I styled the TextView in my TabIndicator that lives in layout:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    style="@style/TabTextStyle"/>
```

This causes my app to crash :\

- If I set TabTextStyle to a fixed color, things are fine.
- If I set the style to ?@android:attr/tabWidgetStyle... things work OK, except the colors are not defined as I want them.

**Does anyone have any ideas?**

Also, I tried to set the color inside the selector, where I select the icons based on state_selected. This causes the icons to disappear.

I can only assume that I missed something and that I am going about this all wrong, but it seems to be as the tutorials say it should be done.

Hope someone can help :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <!-- When selected, use grey -->
 <item android:drawable="@color/black"
      android:state_selected="true" />
 <!-- When not selected, use white-->
 <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Define your own color resources or use android provided resources - "@android:color/black" etc.

Comment: Argh! It seems so obvious now (I figured that the item might have to be a drawable) - I wish I had remote access to try this. Will look into it first thing on Monday and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It Works! The problem was that I needed the selector to be a ColorSelector - not using textColors or drawables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@color/tabTextSelected"/> 
    <item        
        android:color="@color/tabTextUnselected"/>  
</selector>
```